# T-SQL select all IDs that have value A and B

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I'm trying to find all IDs in TableA that are mentioned by a set of records in TableB and that set if defined in Table C. I've come so far to the point where a set of INNER JOIN provide me with the following result:

```
TableA.ID | TableB.Code
-----------------------
1         | A
1         | B
2         | A
3         | B
```

I want to select only the ID where in this case there is an entry for both A and B, but where the values A and B are based on another Query.
I figured this should be possible with a GROUP BY TableA.ID and HAVING = ALL(Subquery on table C).
But that is returning no values.

Comment: Give us sample data and schema please: you mention 3 tables and give us only one which appears to to be 2 tables in one. Also, what did you actually try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not post your original query, I will assume it is inside a CTE.  Assuming this, the query you want is something along these lines:

```
SELECT ID
FROM cte
WHERE Code IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Code) = 2;
```

Comment: The original code was quite complex, so I figured let's bring it back to the core question. But you are right it is using a CTE and utilizing a GROUP BY with HAVING COUNT seems to bring me closer. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's an extremely poor question, but you you probably need to compare distinct counts against table C

```
SELECT a.ID
FROM TableA a
GROUP BY a.ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.Code) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableC)
```

We're guessing though.